# Where is the 'this' pointer stored in computer memory?

Tags: c++, this-pointer

Where exactly is the 'this' pointer stored in memory? Is it allocated on the stack, in the heap, or in the data segment?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
    int a, b;

    public:
        void add()
        {
            a = 10;
            b = 20;
            cout << a << b << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    ClassA obj;
    obj.add();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I am calling the member function `add()` and the receiver object is passed implicitly as the 'this' pointer. Where is `this` stored in memory?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Other answers have done a very good job explaining how a typical compiler implements `this` (by passing it as an implicit first parameter to the function).

I think it's also useful to see what the C++ ISO spec explicitly says about this.  According to the C++03 ISO spec, §9.3.2/1:

> In the body of a nonstatic (9.3) member function, the keyword `this` is a non-lvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called.

It's important to note that `this` is **not** a variable - it's an *expression*, much in the same way that the expression `1 + 2 * 3` is an expression.  The value of this expression is permitted to be stored pretty much anywhere.  The compiler *might* put it on the stack and pass it as an implicit parameter to a function, or it *might* put it in a register, and it conceivably could put it in the heap or in the data segment.  The C++ specification deliberately gives the implementation some flexibility here.

I think that the "language-lawyer" answer is "this is completely implementation-defined, and moreover `this` is technically not a pointer, but an expression that evaluates to a pointer."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 79):

The easiest way is to think of `this` as being a hidden extra argument that is always passed automatically.

So, a fictional method like:

```
size_t String::length(void) const
{
  return strlen(m_string);
}
```

is actually more like this under the hood:

```
size_t String__length(const String *this)
{
  return strlen(this->m_string);
}
```

and a call like:

```
{
  String example("hello");
  cout << example.length();
}
```

becomes something like:

```
cout << String__length(&example);
```

Note that the above transformation is simplified, hopefully to make my point a bit clearer. No need to fill up the comments with "whaaa, where's the marshalling for method overloading, huh?"-type objection, please. :)

That transforms the question into "where are arguments stored?", and the answer is of course "it depends". :)

It's often on the stack, but it could be in registers too, or any other mechanism that the compiler considers is good for the target architecture.

Comment: Good explanation, but I thought __thiscall would most often use `ecx` to store the this pointer.

Comment: AFAIK, this actually *is* a hidden argument of method, am I wrong?

Comment: @Dirk Okay, thanks, I removed that sentence since I'm not very experienced in debugging x86 C++ code at that level.

Comment: @Spook: since it is completely transparent to the user, this argument is meaningless. It is probably implemented this way, but what does it change?

Comment: @riv OP wants to know that :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, the only time I've seen it other than in a register is with g++ on Intel 32 bits.

Comment: Not every system has something called `ecx`.

Comment: @Dirk: With Visual Studio, compiling to x86, `__thiscall` **always** uses `ecx` to pass the `this` pointer to a member function *(though the compiler may shuffle it around within the function, if it decides to use that register for something else)*.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx).

Answer (score 37):

`this` is usually passed as a hidden argument of the method (the only difference throughout different calling conventions is *how*).

If you call:

```
myClass.Method(1, 2, 3);
```

Compiler generates the following code:

```
Method(&myClass, 1, 2, 3);
```

Where the first parameter is actually the pointer to `this`.

Let's check the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int a;

public:
    void __stdcall Method(int i)
    {
        a = i;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.Method(5);

    return 0;
}
```

By using `__stdcall` I forced the compiler to pass all parameters through the stack. If you then start the debugger and inspect the assembly code, you'll find something like the following:

```
     myClass.Method(5);
00AA31BE  push        5  
00AA31C0  lea         eax,[myClass]  
00AA31C3  push        eax  
00AA31C4  call        MyClass::Method (0AA1447h)
```

As you see, the parameter of the method is passed through the stack, then address of myClass is loaded to eax register and again pushed on the stack. In other words, `this` is treated as a regular parameter of this method.

Comment: I would caution against saying that `this` is *always* passed as an implicit first parameter to the function.  This is how most implementations make `this` work, but there's no requirement that this actually has to occur.  Other implementations are possible.

Comment: Technically this is true, however I haven't encountered other implementation than the implicit parameter yet, in the vast majority of cases you can safely assume this case. However, to be technically correct, I changed *always* to *usually*, that should be loose enough.

Answer (score 18):

`this` is an rvalue (you cannot take its address), so it doesn't
(necessarily) occupy memory at all.  Depending on the compiler
and the target architecture, it will often be in a register: i0
on a Sparc, ECX with MSVC on Intel, etc.  When the optimizer is
active, it can even move around. (I've seen it in different
registers with MSVC).

Answer (score 11):

`this` behaves mostly like a function argument, and as such will be stored on the stack or - if the binary calling conventions of the architecture allow that - in a register.

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't stored at a well-defined location! The object that it points to is stored somewhere, and has a well-defined address, but the address itself does not have a specific home address. It is communicated around in the program. Not only that, but there can be many copies of that pointer.

In the following imaginary `init` function, the object registers itself to receive events and timer callbacks (using imaginary event source objects). So after the registration, there are two additional copies of `this`:

```
void foo_listener::init()
{
   g_usb_events.register(this); // register to receive USB events
   g_timer.register(this, 5);   // register for a 5 second timer
}
```

I a function activation chain, there will also be multiple copies of the this pointer. Suppose we have an object `obj` and call its `foo` function. That function calls the same object's `bar` function, and `bar` calls another function called `update`. Each function activation level has the `this` pointer. It's stored in a machine register, or in a memory location in the stack frame of the function activation.