# C++ this->member variable how is it implemented

Tags: c++

If I am in a member function say Hello() and I call call this->membervariable
How is this implemented? Is this get the address of the this pointer and then offset to the membervariable somehow and then dereference? Keen to get some insight into the mechanics of this.

Blair

Comment: `this` is just a hidden parameter to your member function. It works like any other pointer.

Comment: As you said. You should look at the assembly code generated by your compiler, which is the authoritative resource.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the 'this' pointer stored in computer memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585562/where-is-the-this-pointer-stored-in-computer-memory)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the current instance of the class of which the member function belongs to. It is passed implicitly to every member function (except static functions) call you make.

`this->memberVariable` is like any other pointer dereference, just a shortcut for `(*this).memberVariable`.

Comment: ... and "this->memberVariable" is a "longcut" for "memberVariable". But good for code readability.

Comment: Poor for code readability.  Implies semantics that do not exist.  Better for code readaility is a *sane naming scheme* in which members do not have the same identifiers as parameters.

Comment: @JohnDibling Depends on your point of view, Python forces you to use a `self` variable for members, I find it pretty clear and helpful.

Comment: @Collin:  I think we're not in Python anymore, Toto.

Comment: I have to agree with @JohnDibling on this one -- there are a few cases where `this->` can provide meaningful disambiguation, but most of the time it's just useless noise.

Comment: @JohnDibling I guess my point is, I can't see any arguments that aren't just personal preference to decide between `this->` and some kind of naming scheme like `m_var`. There's no performance difference, the language doesn't care. Personally, I think `this->` is a little ugly and verbose.

Comment: @Collin: The compiler doesn't care -- but the compiler should be a secondary target; your primary target should be other programmers. If you want to write Python, write Python. If you're writing C++, write C++. Don't try to write Python in C++ just because the compiler doesn't stop you though.

Comment: @Collin but in python `self` is passed to member functions explicitly, it isn't just pulled out of thin air in the member function scope.

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah, that would be Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

For every member function 'this' is a parameter which is implicitly passed ... since member functions are shared this is way to distinguish for which object the function is called...remember non virtual function are linked at compile time