# C++ : friends of class and "this" pointer

Tags: c++, this, friend

I have one little question for you :), I understand that every method "secretly" gets "**this**" pointer of some class that they are inside but why that wont happen to "friend" functions ?
Is it because they are NOT methods of class?

Can anyone explain whole machinery, i am very interested in how "this" really works!

thanks in advance! :)

Comment: That's right. `friend` functions are non-member functions, so they don't know anything about `this`. They are just granted access to the non-public members of the class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585562/where-is-the-this-pointer-stored-in-computer-memory

Comment: Consider a common friend function, `Foo operator+(Foo const& a, Foo const& b)` - to which `Foo` should `this` point? Now consider `Foo operator+(Bar const& a, Foo const& b)`, friend of both. Can you even say what the type of `this` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `friend` functions and classes are just used for access control checked by the compiler.
- `friend` functions are just standard functions, so there won't be any differences regarding calling conventions.
- `friend` functions are not member of any class, so no `this` pointer is passed (as done with `static` member functions)

Non-`static` member function of a class will get a *hidden* this pointer (depending on the ABI this is often the first argument), `static` member functions don't get the this pointer because they don't act on instance data.

How exactly the this pointer is passed to a member function heavily depends on the used ABI, which depends on the architecture and operating system. Either it will be pushed on the stack, or it will be passed through a well known register.

Please consider reading "[Where is the 'this' pointer stored in computer memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585562/where-is-the-this-pointer-stored-in-computer-memory/16585669)".

Comment: Be careful. C++ standard does not say, that *this* should be passed as first hidden argument (though *usually* it is done this way)

Answer (score 2):

"Friendship" and "Membership" are two different things. A function can be a member function or not, and independantly be a friend function or not.

You can declare a member function to be a friend function of another class, i.e.

```
class B{

   friend void A::func(B);
   //stuff
};
```

Here, the member function `func` from class A is declared as friend and can access B's private, and it will have a `this` pointer, that points to the object of class A on which `func` has been called.

The this pointer is an *implicit* parameter of non-static member functions, which is described in section 9.3.2 of the C++ Standard. How it is passed to the function depends on your compiler/architecture, i.e. it is implementation defined (so you might want to read your favorite compiler's documentation to learn about how it manages `this` pointers).