# where this pointer stored in object of empty class

Tags: c++

class does not have any data member but it has some method . in this case the size of object of class is 1 byte.this pointer which is passed with object when member function is invoked . how is it possible object of 1 byte have this pointer - This pointer typically has size of void* and assume it is 4 bytes

Comment: `char` is also 1 byte and can have pointer to it (`char*`).

Comment: The `this` pointer is not "passed with object" as you say.

Comment: This pointer doesn't belong to the Class object. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585562/where-is-the-this-pointer-stored-in-computer-memory for more info.

Comment: The `this` pointer is **not** a class member, it is the location in memory where the class object is stored. An external object holds the pointer to the object which is (notionally) assigned to the `this` pointer when the method is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

**this** doesn't belong to the Class object. this behaves mostly like a function argument. In your question "this pointer which is passed with object when member function is invoked", I would like to point out that *this* is not passed with object, Object address is passed to the *this* pointer.

Please refer [Where is the 'this' pointer stored in computer memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585562/where-is-the-this-pointer-stored-in-computer-memory) for more info on *this*.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a pointer in C/C++ is always equal to the size of memory address length. (4 bytes)

The size of an class of empty fields is using a separate address. (1 byte)

if we have a class instance of this type, when you count it's size by

sizeof(instance) == 1

but

sizeof(&instance) == 4 (on 32 bits system)

so you can put an address of instance to a pointer like:

void *p = &instance;

here sizeof(p) == 4;

This needs 4 bytes to hold the address/pointer to instance.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` pointer is not a class member, the compiler adds it to the method calls behind the scenes as a *hidden* parameter.

Consider:

```
struct Object
{
    void method(int i);
};
```

The compiler turns that into something like:

```
void Object::method(Object* this, int i); // note the extra first parameter
```

When you do:

```
Object object;
object->method(5);
```

The compiler does something like:

```
Object object;
Object::method(&object, 5);
```

The *hidden* first parameter is called `this`.